# Meaning of "entresucer"

Tags: sens, verbes

I'm reading *Michel Houellebecq*'s *Rudi* ( small *Elle* edition from 2000 ) and I stumbled upon this sentence:

> ...pendant que Pam et Barbara continuaient à s'enlacer et s'entresucer dans le grand lit.

I understand the meaning and that **entresucer** is derivative of **sucer**, but there is no verb like this in vocabulary. Is this some kind of slang?

Comment: You won't find an entry *entresucer* in a dictionary but prefix *entre* can be used to form lots of verbs (or nouns) that show reciprocity. See [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entre-) for examples of such words. Most of the time we'd hyphenate the word. *Entresucer* is no more/as much slang as *sucer*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you @Laure.

Comment: @Laure This is an answer in comments... why so ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very rare word already present in *La Bouquinade*, a poem attributed to Pierre Ronsard.

There are many similar verbs built using the same pattern, like for example *[s'entre-dévorer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/se%20entre-d%C3%A9vorer)* and *s'entretuer* (i.e. to *verb* each other).